# Issue with Hibernate entity.data in thread dumps?

Tags: hibernate, orm, thread-dump

I took some thread dumps for my application during load test and found that all my Cacheable read_only entities are registered in it with some locks. I also see  .data files written on the disk. Is this normal? What is being written on the file .data?

I use the following annotation :

```
@Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
```

Threaddump stacktrace:

```
"some.come.entity.SomeEntity.data" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f9fad47f000 nid=0x7b2e waiting on condition [0x00007f9ef74b3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000073ff0f098> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```